# Awesome WM 4 run_or_raise function

Tags: configuration, awesome-wm

I start to use Awesome 4.0 afters many years on awesome 3.5.

I used aweror lib (you can see it here: https://github.com/lkonga/awesomewm-config) for have a "run or raise" functionality, but I don't find how can I have it with the version 4.0.

Anybody knows how have it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be available via the `awful.client.run_or_raise` function:

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/classes/client.html#awful.client.run_or_raise

Usage from the documentation:

```
-- run or raise urxvt (perhaps, with tabs) on modkey + semicolon
awful.key({ modkey, }, 'semicolon', function ()
    local matcher = function (c)
        return awful.rules.match(c, {class = 'URxvt'})
    end
    awful.client.run_or_raise('urxvt', matcher)
end);
```